# add masking to an animating uiimageview in ios

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, calayer, masking

I am creating a basic animation of opening and closing of doors(like in a lift, its two doors slide back and fro). I have used CABasicAnimation for translation of two doors(two imageview).

My problem is when the door(imageview) slides out, the image of the door comes out of the frame; hence I am using masking property of CALayer but I can't get the expected result.

I want the part of image of door to get masked which comes out of frame while sliding out and it should appear again while sliding in.

thanks mates.

Answer (score 2):

set the property "clip subview" of the view containing this imageview as its subview in the nib file might help you

Comment: I got the result using layer's masking properties. thank you khushboo for suggestion